# Calculate $\sin(z)/(z+i)$ using Cauchy Integral Formula on region $|z+i|=3$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

I just want to know what I'm doing wrong here.  So we have a singularity at $z=-i$ but this is inside the region of circle centered at $-i$ with radius 3.  Hence by Cauchy Integral Formula we have $2\pi i \sin(-i)$ as our final result.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Okay, phew.  My answer key told me that the answer was zero for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct, but it can be simplified further. Since $ \sin(-i) = -i\sinh(1)$, we have $2\pi i \sin(-i) = 2\pi \sinh(1)$.